# Speech services in web chat - text to speech - how to ignore some text in responses

Tags: botframework

In my web chat, I have my intent handling code responding with some text with embedded hyper-links so the user can click on these from the chat window.  This works fine until I enabled speech and now those hyperlinks are being spoken.  Is there a markup I can use in my text responses so that the speech services ignore certain text like the hyper-links?

Thanks

Larry

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a markup I can use in my text responses so that the speech services ignore certain text like the hyper-links?

You can detect hyperlink from text by using regular expression, and then explicitly specify text to be displayed and text to be spoken like below:

```
var mes = "For details, please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/faqs";

var res = "";

if (Regex.Match(mes, @"http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?").Success)
{
    res = Regex.Replace(mes, @"http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?", "the link");
}

await context.SayAsync(text: $"{mes}", speak: $"{res}");
```

***Test result:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would make an `IMessagActivityMapper` that does checks like that for you. This way it will check every response you send back in one place rather than having to do it everywhere you send a url back.

```
public sealed class TextToSpeakActivityMapper : IMessageActivityMapper
{
    public IMessageActivity Map(IMessageActivity message)
    {
        // only set the speak if it is not set by the developer.
        var channelCapability = new ChannelCapability(Address.FromActivity(message));

        if (channelCapability.SupportsSpeak() && string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Speak))
        {
            message.Speak = Regex.Replace(message.Text, @"http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?", "the link");
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

Then register it in your Global.asax.cs file:

```
builder.RegisterType<TextToSpeakActivityMapper>()
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .SingleInstance();
```